# what is the need of ForeignKey( Room ) in the given code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**> `what is the use of the foreign key room needed in this code and what** **> happens when we implement this foreign key room in our code` please help guys just a beginners in Django world **

```
> class Message(models.Model):
>     # user = 
>     room = models.ForeignKey(**Room**, on_delete=CASCADE)   
>     body = models.TimeField()
>     updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
>     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
> 
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.body[0:50]
```

Comment: A foreign key is needed when linking tables. Read up on SQL at some tutorial site, such as w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess, with an example ....
Suppose you have a message id like 1,2,3,4,5 and so on...

I think room represent the channel or chat group .... so now you message id 1,2,5 is linked to room id 1 and message id 3,4 is linked to room 2.

this is to categorize and find all the messages related to a room. since message have a different model, room helps to find which message is from which room.